# ScriptControl client id within a user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I've got a custom script control, or what I call a composite control with a client side object, that I'm trying to use within a user control.  The problem is the user control is changing the control id. So when I wire up the events with the code below the ids are wrong.

comboBox.OnClientLoad = "function(sender, eventArgs){" + Common.FindScriptObject(this.ClientID) + ".ComboBoxLoad(sender,eventArgs); }";

The Common.FindScriptObject code just outputs $find('').  Because it is being used within a user control the client side ids have an some extra lenght to them, like "usercontrol_controlclientId" vs "controlclientId".  So how do I get the ids to be correct within a usercontrol?

Comment: Think I figured it out, just moved the code above to prerender event and the clientID is correct.  Had it in create child controls before.

Answer (score 0):

the control needs to have been added to the control tree first.